# Get all matching elements in nearest parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I click on one of the buttons, all `<p>s` only in the encapsulating div should be given yellow background.
Ideally I would like to see `$(this)`, `parent` and matching elements selector in the jquery selector.
Update: Sorry I did not make my request clear.
I would like to see the selectors of the parent div, the elements I would like to select in the parent and `$(this)` all in select clause.
Say you want to get `<p>` elements from `.left div`, you can extend the selector clause like this
`$("p", ".left")` - Gets all `<p>` in `.left`
In my case, I would like to get hold of `.left` using the `$(this)`, while this "is" button.
Should be in the lines of
`$("p", $(this).closest("body > div"))`

[Heres the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkTpu/1/)
Code.

```
    <style>
    div p.painted {
        background-color: #FF0;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui">
                <div class="colors">
                    <button class="paint">Paint it yellow!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum 
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui">
                <div class="colors">
                    <button class="paint">Paint it yellow!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum 
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(".paint").click(PaintIt);
    });

    function PaintIt(){
        $(this).closest("p").addClass("painted");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of closest to select all `<p>s`. here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkTpu/4/).

Comment: +1 for correct answer to my "ill-formed" question. My bad. I have updated the question to reflect what I exactly want.

Comment: Hmm. Is this what you mean?? Can't you add another class to left/right div to get them using closest()? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fkTpu/6/

Comment: Yes, I can. Just dont want to pollute my already bloated html page. Also I am learning different ways of selecting elements. Hence specified what to be in the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` selects the closest parent of the selected element, according to your markup, at first you should select a parent element then select/find the paragraph elements.

```
$(this).closest("div").siblings('p').addClass("painted");
```

or:

```
$(this.parentNode).siblings('p').toggleClass("painted");
```

or:

```
$(this.parentNode).closest('div').find('p').toggleClass("painted");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nKPFv/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works
`$("p", $(this).closest("body > div"))`
Dont know why it did not while testing it out!

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkTpu/5/)